# Gmail sync with civicrm

Tags: contacts

I just wondered if anyone was currently using the extensions which sync contacts and emails with gmail? I’m Thinking particularly of:

CiviGmail Integration 
Google Apps Sync

I wasn’t sure if they were still compatible with current versions of Civicrm (I use it with drupal)

If anyone is using them I’d be interested to know it before I have a go at installing them!

Comment: As a reminder, this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and questions should have definitive answers. Open-ended requests for reviews, suggestions, tips, and so on are ill-suited to the Stack Exchange format.